# How to programmatically retrieve Amazon RDS recommendations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

I'd want to know if my RDS instance is using previous generations types and I found out that Amazon provides an RDS recommendations that includes if an RDS instance is using a previous generation however I can't seem to find the appropriate API to check Amazon's recommendation programmatically

I reviewed botocore3, AWS CLI, and AWS RDS API but I can't seem to find the appropriate command or API for this rds:DescribeRecommendationGroups

What I tried is I use the AWS Management Console to view Amazon RDS Recommendations. and found out that AWS can provide recommendations if an RDS instance is used previous generation through the console,
I was trying to look if I can do the same action through AWS CLI or boto3 however I only found out that it is only permission

Comment: Seems like currently, there is no API for DescribeRecommendationGroups, you can see the complete list here [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrds.html) If you search for DescribeRecommendationGroups in this page, you would see the link to DescribeRecommendationGroups API is broken ie not available.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the link to the documentation, I was able to  find the RDS recommendations through the Management Console and guessed if there were APIs or a command to get those recommendations, it seems that the API is not available to CLI or boto3

Comment: I'd just want to determine if my rds instances are using previous outdated generation, do you have any suggestions for doing this programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as of march May 7, 2023, you can see Amazon RDS's provided best practice recommendations for your database instances including if your database instance is using a previous generation type through the management console, it is not supported to get Amazon RDS's recommendations via AWS CLI or AWS SDKs.

However, I'd create a python script that could check if a database instance used an older generation type and if there is newer generation type.
the script will check all of your RDS instances if there are available newer generation type based on the database enginee

```
def get_rds_instances():
    """Get all RDS instances"""
    rds = boto3.client('rds')
    db_instances = rds.describe_db_instances()
    for db_instance in db_instances['DBInstances']:
        db_instance_identifier = db_instance['DBInstanceIdentifier']
        new_instance_class = db_instance['DBInstanceClass'][3] + \
            str(int(db_instance['DBInstanceClass'][4]) + 1)
        db_instance_engine = db_instance['Engine']
        check_rds_instance_type(db_instance_identifier,
                                new_instance_class, db_instance_engine)


def check_rds_instance_type(db_instance_identifier: str,
                            db_instance_class: str, db_instance_engine: str):
    """Check if a RDS's instance type is using previous generation instance type"""
    rds = boto3.client('rds')
    orderable_db_instances = rds.describe_orderable_db_instance_options(
        Engine=db_instance_engine, MaxRecords=10000)
    available_instance_classes_query = "{DBInstanceClasses:*[].DBInstanceClass}"
    available_instance_classes = jmespath.search(
        expression=available_instance_classes_query, data=orderable_db_instances)
    new_family_types_query = f"DBInstanceClasses[?contains(@, `{db_instance_class}`) == `true`]"
    new_family_types = jmespath.search(
        expression=new_family_types_query, data=available_instance_classes)
```